# ImportError: No module named 'google.appengine'

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

**Problem**: Unable to call google.appengine.api package inside python code.

```
luser@Ubuntu:~/home/luser/scripts $ python gcp.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gcp.py", line 2, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import app_identity
ImportError: No module named 'google.appengine'
```

Things I have tried and verified and supporting information:

```
    luser@Ubuntu:~/home/luser/scripts $ env | grep PYTHON
    CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
    PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google
```

```
    main_user@Ubuntu:~/home/main_user $ sudo find / -type d -name *google-cloud-sdk*
    /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine
    /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/php/sdk/google
    /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/google-api-python-client
    /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google
    /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/graphy/backends/google_chart_api
```

```
    luser@Ubuntu:~/home/luser/scripts $ gcloud info
    Google Cloud SDK [283.0.0]

    Platform: [Linux, x86_64] uname_result(system='Linux', node='xxxx-Ubuntuxxxxxx', release='4.15.0-88-generic', version='#88~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 12 04:19:15 UTC 2020', machine='x86_64', processor='x86_64')
    Locale: ('en_CA', 'UTF-8')
    Python Version: [3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]]
    Python Location: [/usr/bin/python]
    Site Packages: [Disabled]
```

Comment: what do you want to do with app engine?, as  Dustin Ingram mentioned on the another question this package is not available for python 3

Comment: Hi. The code is trying to connect to gcp - cloud storage. The link provided by Dustin helped me to connect to gcp using the libray "from google.cloud import storage" as compared to the appengine. However, it does not address why gcp does not allow using appengine library beyond python 2.7

Comment: Hi since python 2.7 is now deprecated, the app engine package is not maintained for python 3 in favor to use the client libraries for each product (storage, datastore, compute engine,etc...), this is more like a design decision by Google